# Will upgrading windows affect my ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, updates, windows, windows-10

I read that if I upgrade windows with a linux partition, window will not recognize the ubuntu partition(ext4) and will overwrite the partition, deleting the ubuntu partition. Is there a way I can upgrade windows without affecting my ubuntu partition at all?

Comment: I have upgraded win 7 to win 10 on a few machines with various versions of Ubuntu installed in a dual boot format. I have never heard of windows blowing the Ubuntu installs away. Where did you READ this? 4 machines in the last month along with versions from 16.04 lts to 20.04 lts.

Comment: I see. I'll upgrade it then. There were many cases when updating windows deleted linux partition, you can just google that.